# Implementation of getline ( istream& is, string& str )

Tags: c++, string

My Question is very simple, how is getline(istream, string) implemented?
How can you solve the problem of having fixed size char arrays like with getline (char* s, streamsize n ) ?
Are they using temporary buffers and many calls to new char[length] or another neat structure?

Comment: Implementation-defined, but probably a fixed-size `char` array and `string::append` when it gets full or you get to the end of the line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`getline(istream&, string&)` is implemented in a way that it reads a line. There is no definitive implementation for it; each library probably differs from one another.

Possible implementation:

```
istream& getline(istream& stream, string& str)
{
  char ch;
  str.clear();
  while (stream.get(ch) && ch != '\n')
    str.push_back(ch);
  return stream;
}
```

Comment: So the class string uses a fixed buffer and resizes this buffer if nesseray?

Comment: So they probably use a neat typ of structure or are you talking of arrays which is automatically resized?

Comment: @mjjoker it's just dynamic arrays (`new[]`) like `vector` uses internally. (This is why I say teach the C of C++ before the ++ (either that or trolling))

Comment: I agree with you, but even if you use new[] you have a fixed size! You can recall it and change the size of the array but you have a size!

Comment: @mjjoker, actually you *can't* change the size of an array allocated with `new[]`. With `*alloc` family of functions it is sometimes possible. With C++ we sometimes speak in higher level terms, and for example `string` is referred to as a dynamic array of chars (kind of), regardless of how it's actually implemented.

Comment: @mjjoker yes, with `new[]` you have a fixed size, so when you need a bigger one, you just allocate a new array with `new[]` that is bigger than the old one, copy all the elements over, deallocate the old one and start using the bigger one. When that one gets full, you do the same process again.

Comment: @all thx for your quick and detailed answers. 
But I really know that your - not in a good way - cannot change the size of a a new[] allocated array, even for me it is commen sense to allocate a new array and copy alls chars, but thats not what a would call dynamic, in my humble opinion  - a list is dynamic because in case of add you just need to allocate enough memory for that element.
But still, many thanks for your effort :)

Comment: If an exception occurs, `str` may contain a partial result - better to create a local string in `getline`, append to that and then move the local string to `str` on completion.

Comment: If you use this implementation in a `while` loop let's say, you will still need to read `line` one more time after the loop, you will not get the last item from this `getline` inside the `while` loop like we are used to do.

Answer (score 5):

@SethCarnegie is right:  more than one implementation is possible.  The C++ standard does not say which should be used.

However, the question is still interesting.  It's a classic computer-science problem.  Where, and how, does one allocate memory when one does not know in advance how much memory to allocate?

1. One solution is to record the string's characters as a *linked list* of individual characters.  This is neither memory-efficient nor fast, but it works, is robust, and is relatively simple to program.  However, a standard library is unlikely to be implemented this way.
2. A second solution is to allocate a buffer of some fixed length, such as 128 characters.  When the buffer overflows, you allocate a new buffer of double length, 256 characters, then copy the old characters over to the new storage, then release the old.  When the new buffer overflows, you allocate an even newer buffer of double length again, 512 characters, then repeat the process; and so on.
3. A third solution combines the first two.  A linked list of character arrays is maintained.  The first two members of the list store (say) 128 characters each.  The third stores 256.  The fourth stores 512, and so on.  This requires more programming than the others, but may be preferable to either, depending on the application.

And the list of possible implementations goes on.

Regarding standard-library implementations, @SteveJessop adds that "[a] standard library's string isn't permitted to be implemented as (1), because of the complexity requirement of `operator[]` for strings. In C++11 it's not permitted to be implemented as (3) either, because of the contiguity requirement for strings. The C++ committee expressed the belief that no active C++ implementation did (3) at the time they added the contiguity requirement. Of course, `getline` can do what it likes temporarily with the characters before adding them all to the string, but the standard does say a lot about what string can do."

The addition is relevant because, although `getline` could temporarily store its data in any of several ways, if the data's ultimate target is a string, this may be relevant to `getline`'s implementation.  @SteveJessop further adds, "For string itself, implementations are pretty much required to be (2) except that they can choose their own rate of expansion; they don't have to double each time as long as they multiply by some constant."

Comment: A standard library's `string` isn't *permitted* to be implemented as (1), because of the complexity requirement of `operator[]` for strings. In C++11 it's not permitted to be implemented as (3) either, because of the contiguity requirement for strings. The C++ committee expressed the belief that no active C++ implementation did (3) at the time they added the contiguity requirement. Of course, `getline` can do what it likes temporarily with the characters before adding them all to the `string`, but the standard does say a lot about what `string` can do.

Comment: @SteveJessop:  Your comment is better than my answer.  If you haven't the time or interest to edit the answer in light of your comment, then I'll edit it myself.  If I understand your comment correctly, implementation (2) is the only probable one -- or is there an implementation (4) as well?

Comment: @SteveJessop he's talking about the implementation of `getline` I am thinking, not of `string`. Also thb, for any implementation number `n`, there is always an implementation `n + 1` :)

Comment: The reason I made it a comment is that the question asks how `getline` can be implemented, and I'm just remarking how `string` must be implemented in C++. What you say is still true of the classic computer-science problem, and `getline` could do any of the things you say, and then at the end it could copy all the characters from its own data-structure into a `string`. For `string` itself, implementations are pretty much required to be (2) except that they can choose their own rate of expansion, they don't have to double each time as long as they multiply by some constant.

Comment: So while there probably is a 4, it will look fairly 2-ish around the edges :-) For example the "small string optimization" is sometimes used, and an implementation is permitted (although I don't specifically remember hearing of any) to do implementation-specific things that will use memory more efficiently provided that `::operator new` hasn't been overridden by the user. For example, it could ask for sizes that it "just so happens" to know are convenient for the system's `malloc` implementation, so as hopefully not to waste bytes at the end of blocks.

Comment: You could do number 2 easily by calling `std::string::reserve` to grow the buffer and `std::string::capacity` to check the size.  After each character added, if the size exceeds the capacity, double the capacity.  Maybe std::string does this already.

Answer (score 0):

As @3bdalla said, implementation of thb doesn't work as gnu implementation. So, I wrote my own implementation, which works like gnu's one. I don't know what will be with errors in this variant, so it needs to be tested.
My implementation of getline:

```
std::istream& getline(std::istream& is, std::string& s, char delim = '\n'){
    s.clear();
    char c;
    std::string temp;
    if(is.get(c)){
        temp.push_back(c);
        while((is.get(c)) && (c != delim))
            temp.push_back(c);
        if(!is.bad())
            s = temp;
        if(!is.bad() && is.eof())
            is.clear(std::ios_base::eofbit);
    }
    return is;
}
```

Comment: Might it be more efficient to find the delimiter, then `seekg` back to the original position and `readsome` the whole thing into the output string at once, so that the output string doesn't have to dynamically resize?

Comment: @nog642, sounds great! You can add your own variant of answer below, so everybody can see it)

Comment: You might not be able to seekg on the input, like if it comes from a pipe.